# What are the differences between "to think: to have a particular idea or opinion about something" & "to think: to have ideas in your mind"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/think_1?q=think),

> to think: [transitive, intransitive] (not used in the progressive
>   tenses) to have a particular idea or opinion about something/somebody;
>   to believe something
>
> Ex: **Do you think (that) they’ll come?** (we don't say: are you thinking
>   they'll come)
>
> to think: [transitive] (usually used in the progressive tenses) to
>   have ideas, words or images in your mind
>
> Ex: **You're very quiet. What are you thinking?** (It sounds strange
>   if we say: You're very quiet. What do you think?)

So **what are the differences between:**

> I think he might be good for us.
>
> I am thinking he might be good for us. (Maybe there will have some pauses between "... thinking" & "he might...")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excellent question!

In a sentence, I could say:

> I think she's pretty.

This means that, **in my opinion**, this certain person is attractive.

Now, for the other instance:

> I think about her quite frequently.

This version means that **I think** about this person quite frequently. This person is in my thoughts, while the first example says *only* that I believe that the person is attractive.

There is no verbal difference between these two, though the main difference in their usage depends on the situation - to review, while both say '*I think*', one expresses an opinion, while the other only refers to what we're thinking about.

I hope my explanation made sense. Feel free to ask any questions!